# UITabBarItem execute an IBAction Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

i want to be able to make an IBaction execute when i click on a tabbar item.. I am using the default tab bar template that Xcode 4.2 has, and i understand how to link an IB Action to a Button... But, i am running into difficulty when trying to link an IBaction to a tabBaritem (at the bottom of the screen). So when someone clicks one of my tabs, an action is executed?

How can this action be performed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a good thing to try and use a tab bar as a toolbar, there is a UI element for that. If you really want to run an action when clicking on a tab bar button, you need to add it to the controller that is activated by the button.

Comment: exactly - use `UIToolbar` instead.

Comment: I agree, but as a developer you don't always have control over the designs. I also have a requirement to have some actions be performed from a tab bar. So i will need a workaround for this

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting your ViewController to be a UITabBarDelegate then giving a tag for each of the tab bar items (I tagged them 0, 1 and 2). Then implement the UITabBarDelegate method as shown below. Simply replace "[self performTaskXXX]" with whatever code you need to run.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{  
    switch (item.tag) {
    case 0:
        [self performTaskOne];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self performTaskTwo];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self performTaskThree];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```